# Calculating the volume of a $4$-simplex with edges of length $1$

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> In the Euclidean space $(\mathbb{E}^{4})$, consider a $4$-simplex $S$ with vertices $P_{0}, P_{1}, P_{2}, P_{3}, P_{4}$. Assume that the edges of the simplex $S$ have a length of $1$.
>
> (a) Calculate the volume of the simplex $S$.
>
> (b) Determine the distance from the vertex $P_{4}$ to the plane $\alpha$ passing through the vertices $P_{0}, P_{1}, P_{2}, P_{3}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.